# What is the proper CSS selector for a selected label?

Tags: html, css

What is the proper CSS selector for a selected label for the following code?

```html
<div class="form-group Info1">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label Label1" for="1">Some Label Text</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9 Data1">
            <input id="1" class="form-control" 
                   type="radio" checked="" value="1" 
                   title="" alt="" name="SomeLabel">
        </div>
</div>
```

When the radio is selected I want to apply formatting, like a `:hover`. I realize it is `:checked`, but it ignores me.

Comment: Do you mean you want to select the label of a user-selected radio button?

Comment: `.Label1 {....`

Comment: `.col-sm-3.control-label.Label1`

Comment: There isn't one for that structure.

Comment: Like Paulie_D said, there isn't one, but if you could move the label after the input you can do input:checked + label {}

Comment: There is, at present, NO selector that can select a previous element **especially** one that does not even share the same parent. You need javascript...or change the structure / layout method.